# Как в питоне составить регулярку для строки вида "слово - слово"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Как в питоне, используя библиотеку re, составить паттерн  для строки формата "слово - слово"?

Comment: Приведите примеры подходящих и неподходящих строк в соответствии с описание метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Comment: `^.*?\s\-\s.*?$`

Comment: "собака - пес" - подходящий
"один, два, три" - не подходящий

Comment: А зачем?! Чем стандартные методы не угодили? `string.split(' - ')`

Comment: английские слова? два пробела?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
^[а-яё]+ - [а-яё]+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/6kkETT/3

> **собака - пес**
>
> один, два, три

Сгенерированный код:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^[а-яё]+ - [а-яё]+$"

test_str = ("собака - пес\n"
    "один, два, три")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: Та за шо минус?

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov про большие буквы же ничего не сказано